# Java web application rapid development tool - Driven by meta-data

Tags: java, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, web

We are planing to use AngularJS, Bootstrap, jQuery, Javascript, CSS for a web application development.

My boss is suggesting to build a tool that would read the metadata (could be from DB) and build the web application without or less coding. So that in future to add any new pages he would just create/edit the metadata.

To me it seems too complicated and may not be possible as it does not give flexibility. Please suggest.

**Upadate:-**

Have any one build such tool ? Is it worth the effort ? Or should be a definite no no to such approach ?

I have found one tool called evolutility. http://evoluteur.github.io/evolutility

Have anyone used this ?

Comment: What kind of data are we talking here?  If there's low variety in the types of data received, then you're not too far off of something like a blog app (simple to modularize various components of the site and modify them via DB), but I get the sense that this is something more in depth than that.

Comment: @NickM Thanks, its complex than simple blogs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [WaveMaker](http://www.wavemaker.com/studio)? It generates application that matches the stack you mentioned.

Also, your DB seems local, WaveMaker have on premise version which can help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.